# Everyday phenomena for physicists

Tags: resource-recommendations, everyday-life, applied-physics

I am a physicist by training and like to learn more about everyday phenomena, i.e. how things work.

All books on this rather general topic go in the direction of introducing physics, they want to transport fascination to the reader and help people to think like scientists think.

It is a long time now that I am looking for something more advanced. Ofcourse it is interesting to know how a coffee machine works or lighting is induced. But I would love to read about it in detail, on the basis of physical laws, and why not using some formulas?

Have you encountered books like these?

Comment: There are a large number of questions and answers on this site that might address some of your hunger for this knowledge. Start with the everyday-life tag...

Comment: [Bloomfield has a few books like this](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP000190.html), but I've never read them so I cannot vouch for them (though they do seem aimed for not-physicists)

Answer (score 3):

Physics papers and books from 18th and 19th century by Kelvin, Rayleigh and J.J. Thomson and other physicists who invented lot of physics while thinking about everyday phenomena. You can find them on Internet Archive as their collected papers/works.